# How to Install PCRE Development Headers on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails

I just upgraded my MacBook Pro to Mavericks and my local Ruby on Rails development environment isn't running straight off the bat, when I visit `localhost` I see `It works!` and remembered I needed to start Phusion Passenger, so when I run `passenger start` it checks all the requisites and fails when it gets to the PCRE Development Headers:

```
 * Checking for PCRE development headers...
    Found: no
```

It tells me to go to http://www.pcre.org/ to download them so I downloaded 8.33 from [here](ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/) which went to my `Downloads` folder, so I unzipped it, `cd`'d to the folder and ran:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Then `cd`'d back to my rails app directory on my Desktop and re-ran `passenger start` but it's still the same. Tried a new Terminal window but that didn't make any difference.

I must have done this before to get my dev environment working but can't seem to solve it this time.

I also tried `brew install pcre` but it says `Warning: pcre-8.33 already installed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCRE headers on Mac OS X should be installed in /usr/bin.

You could try adding that to your $PATH.

Another thing to try is explicitly calling it on the commandline: `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/bin/ passenger start`

Lastly you could try reinstalling/recompiling passenger as it may not have groked where the PCRE headers are on your system.

Comment: thanks, tried `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/bin/ passenger start` but same result, will trying uninstalling and reinstalling passenger

Comment: reinstalling did the trick, passenger is now running but `localhost` is still saying `It works!` instead of showing my app, any ideas on that one?

Comment: Delete the index.html file in your app directory.

Comment: thanks but there's no index.html file in the app directory

Comment: The "It Works!" message is an Apache default located in an index.html file somewhere in the web server's default root (where, depends on how your apache is configured).

Comment: yeah, I think the problem is phusion passenger isn't correctly setup yet, just created a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543094/apache-httpd-h-file-missing-macosx, my http.h file is missing somehow and I'm not sure how to repair that

Comment: What does `locate apache2` in the terminal come up with?

Comment: It says `WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.`

Comment: Go ahead and create the database. It's very handy for debugging.

Comment: While you're waiting for that, did you `install passenger-install-apache2-module` using the `sudo` command or `rvmsudo`?

Comment: I tried using the `sudo` command but not the `rvmsudo` command. Got the same error. I think this is actually a common problem with Phusion Passenger after the Mavericks upgrade.

Comment: Yeah, might be related to Xcode. There's an update for it in software updates that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Found this fix at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543094/apache-httpd-h-file-missing-on-macosx-after-mavericks-upgrade

1. Update/install xcode
2. `run xcode-select --install`- Update command line tools

Here are the remaining steps I took to get my site working.

1. disabled/removed MacPorts/Fink
2. `brew install passenger` - re-install homebrew
3. `rvm reinstall 2.0.0` or whatever version
4. `gem uninstall nokogiri` - error with nokogiri
5. `gem install nokogiri`
6. `bundle install`
7. restart terminal

and it worked! As a note, I am betting that if I had just installed passenger, RVM and restarted it would have worked after i did the xcode updates.